# on AWS - could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet aws

Tags: mysql, hibernate, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I have this (common) problem with my DB access. But in my case, I dont find the right answere...

Created a very basic MySql DB and Spring Boot App accessing it.

On my localhost it runs smooth.

Then I dumped the local DB. Inserted it into the AWS-MySql DB. 
And deployed the Spring-Boot app with Docker to my EC2. 
Everything is well.

But on using the AWS MySQL all REST Endpoints return:
status 500
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

For me it looks like all the same as it was on localhost.

What did I miss?

Comment: We would need more details to help you. Database logs, application logs, fullstack trace of the error. My guess is that something wrong with execution permissions?

Comment: Yeah, I had nothing till now. See answere...

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. I know a solution. 
BUT I cant accept to not to know how it happend:

My POJOs are defined by Classname only (no Table="" Metadata decortion)

On my local machine it runs well. 
The SQL query is: `"... 'Dbname'.'tablename' ... "`

Dockerized on AWS on the RDS Mysql.
The SQL query is: `"... 'Dbname'.'TableName' ... "`

And then the of course the query fails.

My configs:

properties:

```
#Hibernate (Spring-JPA)
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

POM:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-services.version>1.5.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

So obviously my NamingStrategy settings will be ignored or overriden in local or aws.

But at this point I could need some help.

PS: And why I cant find any useful documentatins about the Hibernate naming strategy settings?!? e.g.: strat-setting-A => TableName -> TABLE_NAME etc...
Why do I have to read the code to understand this? (T.T)

EDIT:
Hooray! I have the cause. 
My local db config is diffrent. Well its by default: `lower_case_table_names=1`
So it just ignores CamelCase. But on aws it seems to be set to `0` Which means it takes care of camel case names.

So soultion is easy: Setting my naming strategy to lowercase only!
Just WHERE do I find the docs which config is right?? :-)

Well anyway... better no docs then wrong docs!

SOLUTION:

2 Options:

1 - Configuring the POJOs manually with @Table() decorator.
2 - Removing the hibernate naming setting from the properties (or change it to what ever needed)

PS: Iam still interessted into all setting possibilites if someone know a good doc.

Comment: There's no right configuration. The hibernate name config relies on either the configuration you pass to it (annotation Table) or it uses the class names as the names of the tables. This configuration is OS specific read it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html The thing you have to know is that you must know what you are using, if you don't define a Table annotation you should configure your database to ignore it. If you use the annotation this configuration can either be case sensitive or to ignore it.

Comment: Oh, and for the Hibernate docs you didn't search it right. Here it is https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity in section **2.2.1.1** and note that the hibernate configuration has nothing to do with mysql configuration (although they are related) you must know both of then to configure your application right

Comment: Specific the text: If no @Table is defined the default values are used: **the unqualified class name of the entity**.

Comment: And that's why I said we need more details on your question. Not in a million years someone would guess what was wrong with your application without further details that you provided in your answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Your right. I found a JBOSS doc. But it was a different (useless)one. THANKS!

Comment: @JorgeCampos And I meant the "ImplicitNaming" is used. I guess it was written a bit confused.